# React Native Show/Hide View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a file called test.js. It has two Classes A and B. In class B I have a button `hide view`.

What I want is when I click on `hide view` button then it should toggle(show/hide) the view of class A without loading.

How can I do this?

Comment: is class A and class B are two screens?

Comment: Thanks for your response sir,Yes, A and B are two separate screens

Comment: i am not able to understand this line {this.state.showComponmentB && <B/>}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this example:

```
export default class A extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {showComponmentB: true}
  }

  _toggleShow = () => {
    this.setState({showComponmentB: !this.state.showComponmentB})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.showComponmentB && <B/>}
        <Button title="toggle button" onPress={this._toggleShow}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class B extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SomeView/>
    );
  }
}
```